# How to remove nodes based on duplicate elements in an XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to read in an XML document and return a XML document with unique nodes. If there's a node with a duplicate element named `compoundName`, that parent node should be removed.

```
<scanSegment>
      <index>28</index>
      <GUID>539003de-1379-4a03-94bf-1ede58625ab5</GUID>
      <ionMode>ESI</ionMode>
      <ionPolarity>Positive</ionPolarity>
      <scanType>DynamicMRM</scanType>
      <dataStorage>PeakDetected</dataStorage>
      <threshold>0</threshold>
      <fragmentorMode>Fixed</fragmentorMode>
      <fragmentorRamp />
      <scheduledTime>4.33</scheduledTime>
      <timeWindow>1.2</timeWindow>
      <scheduledSetting>720</scheduledSetting>
      <isTriggeredMRM>false</isTriggeredMRM>
      <numtMRMRepeats>3</numtMRMRepeats>
      <scanElements>
        <scanElement>
          <index>1</index>
          <compoundName>3-keto carbofuran</compoundName>
          <isISTD>false</isISTD>
          <ms1LowMz>236.1</ms1LowMz>
          <ms1Res>Unit</ms1Res>
          <ms2LowMz>208.1</ms2LowMz>
          <ms2Res>Unit</ms2Res>
          <fragmentor>82</fragmentor>
          <deltaEMV>200</deltaEMV>
          <cellAccVoltage>9</cellAccVoltage>
          <collisionEnergy>4</collisionEnergy>
          <isPrimaryMRM>true</isPrimaryMRM>
          <isTriggerMRM>false</isTriggerMRM>
          <triggerEntranceDelayTime>0</triggerEntranceDelayTime>
          <triggerDelayTime>0</triggerDelayTime>
          <triggerWindow>0</triggerWindow>
          <triggerMRMThreshold>0</triggerMRMThreshold>
          <compoundGroup>
          </compoundGroup>
        </scanElement>
      </scanElements>
    </scanSegment>
```

The element named "compoundName" is nested within scanElement and scanElements... I'm having trouble filtering through the XML document to check if the element "compoundName" is unique.

I've read through some examples that have the LINQ format like

```
xmlDoc.Descendants("scanSegment").GroupBy().Where().Remove()
```

and I'm not sure how to fill out the rest of the query.

Comment: `compoundName` is an element and no attribute. I changed that in your question to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Could you give us an example which *does* have a duplicate, along with what you'd want the output to be? (Also, most of the rest of the elements are irrelevant - it may be worth keeping a few to show the structure, but we don't need that many.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove these duplicate elements is applying an XSLT-stylesheet to your XML. The [Sample code is described here at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/inputs-to-the-xslcompiledtransform-class). I modified it to suit your needs.
`source.xml` is the input file, `trans.xslt` the XSLT file and `destination.xml` the output file.

```
// Open books.xml as an XPathDocument.
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("source.xml");    
// Create a writer for writing the transformed file.
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("destination.xml");
// Create and load the transform with script execution enabled.
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
settings.EnableScript = true;
transform.Load("trans.xslt", settings, null);    
// Execute the transformation.
transform.Transform(doc, writer);
```

Here is the XSLT-1.0 file `trans.xslt`. The task you want to apply is achieved in one template by the expression `scanElement[count(compoundName) > 1]`. It discards all `scanElement`s which have a count of more than one `compoundName` children.

So essentially, you can achieve your filtering in one line of XSLT code. It is accompanied by the *identity template* which copies all of the nodes on which no other template applies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>

    <!-- Identity template - this template is applied by default to all nodes and attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

   <xsl:template match="*[count(compoundName) > 1]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This will remove all the duplicates (that is, if there are two elements with the same name, it will remove both). That might be what the OP wanted, but it would be an unusual requirement. There are of course solutions using XSLT 1.0 (Muenchian grouping) or XSLT 2.0 (xsl:for-each-group).

Comment: There is no necessity to remove duplicates. The task at hand is solely to eradicate all elements that have more than one `compoundName` element children. So no _Grouping_ at all, neither 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Interesting. Your reading of the question is entirely different from mine, but equally valid. Just shows how difficult it is to write unambiguous requirements.

Comment: I am fascinated by your response and I am trying to apprehend and _comprehend_ your comment. And I am also trying to process your riddle of how to process several aspects of a given situation.

Comment: It all depends on what you think "with a duplicate element named compoundName" means. My interpretation was "having the same string value for child::compoundName as some other element", but there are many other possible interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement scanElements = doc.Descendants("scanElements").FirstOrDefault();

            List<XElement> uniqueScanElements = scanElements.Elements("scanElement")
                .Select(x => new { compoundName = (string)x.Element("compoundName"), scanElement = x })
                .GroupBy(x => x.compoundName)
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                .Select(x => x.scanElement)
                .ToList();

            scanElements.ReplaceWith(new XElement("scanElements"), uniqueScanElements);
        }
    }
}
```